# use two models in one view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

net MVC 5 I have a view that require info from two models. In one modelView i have Student Marks and in the other, I have Student details How do I call both models to the view.

public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public int StudentNum { get; set; }

```
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public string StudentSurname { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Marks
{
    [Key]
    public int Mark1 { get; set; }

    public int Mark2 { get; set; }

    public int Dp { get; set; }

    public int StudentNum { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new View Model which encapsulates both the other view models as,

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public Details Details { get; set; }

    public Marks Marks { get; set; }
}
```

and pass it to the view you use. And access by Model.StudentViewModel.Details for getting student details and for marks Model.StudentViewModel.Marks.